# 2 arrays one of values one of colors make D3 bar chart have color at same index of value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, charts

I have 2 arrays:

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5,4,7,2,9,10];
colors = ['red','red','blue','blue','green','green','orange','orange','pink','pink'];
```

I am trying to build a D3 Bar chart where each bar has height of 10 times the value and corresponds to the color that has the same index as the value.

This is what I have so far:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
            .data(total_data)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .style("fill", function(d) {
                return colors[values.indexOf(d)];
            })
```

However, say we have a duplicate value then it will return the wrong color. I also tried to create a JSON from the 2 arrays and then pass that in as the data but I was having trouble with this. What is the best way to do the above? Thanks!

Comment: Zip the values and colours together in a new data array, and use that to feed into d3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you only want each bar having a colour that...

> corresponds to the color that has the same index as the value

You just need to access the array `colors` using the index of each bar:

```
.attr("fill", function(d,i){ return colors[i]});
```

Here is a working example (using the width as 10x the value, not the height, for simplicity):

```js
values = [1,2,3,4,5,4,7,2,9,10];
colors = ['red','red','blue','blue','green','green','orange','orange','pink','pink'];

var width = 400, height = 400;

var svg = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);
 
var bars = svg.selectAll(".myBars")
 .data(values)
 .enter()
 .append("rect");
 
bars.attr("x", 10)
 .attr("y", function(d,i){ return 10 + i*40})
 .attr("width", function(d){ return d*10})
 .attr("height", 30)
 .attr("fill", function(d,i){ return colors[i]});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Just a tip: this is not a good approach when you have a big dataset, or when your dataset keeps changing. Instead, use an array of objects in which you can set the color for each object, or create a rule for colouring the bars.

Comment: Can you also explain why you did 

var bars = svg.selectAll(".myBars")
 .data(values)
 .enter()
 .append("rect");

and what .myBars is 

thanks!

Comment: Regarding your second question, that's just an enter selection using svg rectangles. I know that in your example you're using divs, but my snippet is just to show you how to access your array by index.