# How do I get d3.scaleOrdinal

Tags: javascript, d3.js, color-scheme

I have this - I think  relatively simple - code fragment. It works like I want: I get a pie chart with a division according to the basedata. But I can't get the colour scheme I designed, to display. Originally I had basedata in the call to  scaleOrdinal but that makes no difference.
How do I get the colours to display for the corresponding entry in basedata?

```
  const svgContainer = d3.select("#d3").append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", [-60, -60, 120, 120])
    .attr("width", 120)
    .attr("height", 120)
    .attr("style", "display: inline; float: left");

  // Generate the pie
  var basedata = [50, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 39.8, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7];

  var myColor = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .domain([   50,        1.7,        1.7,          1.7,         39.8,          1.7,         1.7,          1.7    ])
    .range( ["yellow", "royalblue", "mediumblue", "darkblue", "midnightblue", "darkblue", "mediumblue", "royalblue"]);

  const arcs = d3.pie()
    .startAngle(-0.5 * Math.PI)
    .sort(null)(basedata);

  const arc = d3.arc()
    .innerRadius(0)
    .outerRadius(120 / 2 - 1);

  const pie = d3.select("svg").append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "black")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(arcs)
    .join("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill", function (d) { return myColor(d) });
```

Comment: Try passing hash codes instead of color names.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I solved it. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39427222/11931424).

Don't use scaleOrdinal. 
Replace the fill command with: `.attr("fill", function (d, i) { return myColor[i] })`